# angular.element(..).scope() returns undefined initially

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to access my angular controller's scope outside of the controller. I am using an external js library which performs certain actions and on completion executes certain callbacks. In one of the callbacks `angular.element(document.findElementById('elementId').scope()` returns `undefined`.
But in the second callback that is executed after the first 
`angular.element(document.findElementById('elementId').scope()` returns the valid scope.

Here is some sample code

```
    <body id="authcontroller" ng-controller="AuthenticationController as auth">

<script>
    window.externalLibObj = {
     onCallback1: function(){
         // Undefined value for scope
         var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('authcontroller')).scope();
     },
     onCallback2(): function(){
        // Valid value for scope
        var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('authcontroller')).scope();
     }
    };
</script>
    </body>
```

The order in which these callbacks are executed are `onCallback1` and then `onCallback2`. `var scope` is undefined in `onCallback1` but has a value in `onCallback2`

Why is `scope` undefined in `onCallback1`?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling these callbacks?

Comment: @PeterLaBanca the code which calls these callbacks is executed automatically once the js lib loads, I never make an explicit call to the code calling these callbacks

Comment: And both callbacks are executed immediately? It just sounds like a timing issue where the scope isn't ready until the 2nd callback is called.

Comment: @PeterLaBanca yes the callbacks are executed the moment the lib finishes loading, callback1 is executed first, followed by callback2 in a sequential manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a timing issue. When your first callback is executed the scope isn't ready, but it is on your second callback. You should change your logic and trigger the callbacks within the controller when the associated view is correctly loaded.

In your AuthenticationController add this:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
  // here define/fire your callbacks and you will be sure that everything is init
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: unfortunately I don't have control over when the callbacks will be triggered, as they are automatically triggered once the js lib I am using loads. Seems like I will need to figure out some other way to get this to work.

Comment: try to use a promise and resolve the promise inside the event of the controller I posted above. Inside your callbacks put the code you need inside the `then` of that promise, and you will have your code executed when the controller has been init. does it make sense?

Comment: was able to get it to work. Thanks for all your help!